# What does Newton's Theorem XXXIII in his book "Principia" mean?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, symmetry, history, planets

> If to the several points of a given sphere there tend equal centripetal forces decreasing in a duplicate ratio of the distances from the points; I say, that a corpuscle placed within the sphere is attracted by a force proportional to its distance from the centre.

https://archive.org/details/newtonspmathema00newtrich/page/n225/mode/1up?view=theater

His well-known theorems XXX and XXXI refer to particles inside/outside a spherical shell. Those experience net forces of zero and proportional to $r^2$ from the center, respectively.

Theorems XXXII and XXXIII refer to some other scenario. I would like to know what that is, but I am having trouble parsing his writing style.

Comment: in that case, by symmetry all the equal centripetal forces would cancel out and there would be no attraction force

Comment: @tac Newton says otherwise in the quote...

Comment: He is just saying that F ∝ 1/d^2 ; but if a corpuscule is inside of sphere then by symmetry all the forces from the points of the sphere will cancel out (Gauss Law)

Comment: @tac Sorry, but that is definately not what he is saying. He clearly concludes there is a net force proportional to r: "There remains, there fore; only the attraction of the interior sphere PEQ,F. And (by Prop. LXXII) this is as the distance PS. Q.E.D." My question is about what scenario he is describing, his meaning on the presence of a force is quite evident.

Comment: If to the several points of a given sphere there tend equal centripetal forces **decreasing in a duplicate ratio** of the distances from the points. *Decreasing in a duplicate ratio* means F ∝ 1/d^2 . He imagined a sphere with a corpuscle in the center and how they would interact

Comment: @tac You are getting closer. Then he says the consequence will be a net force proportional to r for a particle within the sphere. This is in contrast to theorem XXX, where he concludes: "Therefore the body P will not be any way impelled by those attractions. Q.E.D."  You can read it in full at the link I provided. What is the difference between these scenarios?

Comment: @Livid I have never read the _Principia_ and am not familiar with what he usually means by 'sphere', but it seems clear he is talking about a solid ball. In this case, supposing a gravity-like force, one assumes $dF = C \frac{dm}{r^2}$, with the immediate consequence (knowing that the effect of the mass inside the inner ball to the chosen point is summarized by a total mass at the center) that $F(r) = \frac{CM}{R^3}r$, where M and R are the total mass and radius of the sphere, respectively.

Comment: @GaloisFan He never said *solid*. I thought it was *hollow*

Comment: @tac what you thought was clear. I'm explaining what makes sense.

Comment: @GaloisFan okok, we all agree that: If a corpuscle is inside a hollow sphere, then by Gauss Law the net force will be zero; but if it's outside, there will be a net force different from zero where F = ∯ k m dM/r^2 (or something like that). Of course Newton would complicate it more because he didn't have all the same resources and tools we have nowadays to explain it easier

Comment: @tac he is not complicating anything. He is talking about a test mass inside a solid sphere (call it a ball, if you want). In this case, if one is talking of a gravitational force and a homogeneous ball, it is true that, for $r<R$, $F \propto r$.

Comment: Does the accompanying drawing not illustrate it clearly? It's just a statement that the mass external to the point P (that is the shell larger than the radius defined by the point Ps placement) doesn't affect the body. While all that closer to the center does with an inverse square law as were it a point source.

Comment: @GaloisFan if you are at a distance nearer than the radius of the sphere (which is hollow because if it is solid you can't have a corpuscle inside because that would violate the Impenetrability Principle of Matter) then you sum vectorially all the forces that all the particles from the sphere exert in the test corpuscle to get F⃗ = 0⃗

Comment: @tac with all due respect, I think the problem is you are a little too confident that you understand the matter you are discussing.  It is quite simple, really. 1) Any finite solid volume is made up by an infinite amount of volume elements, which in this case are influenced by gravitational forces (there is a lot of pieces of dirt inside the Earth which are being pulled towards its center). 2) Yes, as you are saying for the hundredth time, a spherical shell cannot exert  a net force to a point in its interior, but it does exert one to a force in its exterior.

Comment: @GaloisFan Thanks, the solid vs hollow sphere distinction is at least part of what I was missing. So hes saying the net force on a particle *outside* solid vs hollow spheres is the same (proportional to r^2 directed at the center). But is zero *inside* a hollow sphere, as opposed to proportional to r inside a solid sphere.

Comment: @Livid exactly.

Comment: @GaloisFan Oh, I think I understand. He is not trying to place a particle inside a solid sphere but the particle is from the very same sphere. I missed that part LOL

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The translation is using language differently from how we will use it today. In particular, the word *sphere* should now be reserved to mean the skin of a ball, and *ball* to be a solid ball. Here, the translation is using *constant density solid ball* for the meaning of *sphere,* which is why it can seem utterly confusing. Note, however, that it is just a choice of definition: the translator has been using *sphærical surface* for what modern language calls a sphere, so you should not be confused.

As you also noted, in Theorem XXX Newton proved that a point inside a uniform density sphere will feel no $\frac1{r^2}$ net forces by virtue of them cancelling out, and in Theorem XXXI, it is proved that a point outside a uniform density sphere will feel a net force of $\frac1{r^2}$ directed to the centre of the sphere.

Theorem XXXII just says that if the observation point is right at the surface of a uniformly dense ball of density $\rho$ and radius $R$, then the net force is proportional to $\rho R$, and the reason is just trivial: The solid ball can be mentally decomposed into concentric onion layers, each layer contributing $4\pi r^2\rho\mathrm dr$ worth of mass to gravitationally attract this point, while Theorem XXXI said that the force this shell of mass will provide is proportional to $1/R^2$, where $r\neq R$ except at the surface layer. Integrating all the onion shells, we obtain that the total gravitational pull is proportional to $\frac43\pi R^3\rho/R^2=\frac43\pi\rho R$ as the Theorem requires.

Theorem XXXIII is just the combination of Theorem XXXII and Theorem XXX. Namely, if you dig a hole into Earth, say, you will feel that the gravitational pull will decrease with $r$ as you descend towards the centre.

Now, do note that modern treatments will not make the completely uniformly dense assumption that Newton did. It is very clear that we only require that the density distribution be spherically symmetric, because that is all that is needed for Theorems XXX and XXXI to apply. This is also why it applies well to Earth, say, since our planet is only very slightly non-spherically-symmetric, whereas the density variation with radius varies quite a bit, almost double at the core than at the surface.

Comment: The density of surface rock is about 2.6 g/cc while the density at the very center of the Earth is about 13.1 g/cc. That's a factor of over five rather than "almost double".

Comment: Thanks for the correction, @DavidHammen I only glanced at the first Google result.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149197/discussion-on-answer-by-naturallyinconsistent-what-does-newtons-theorem-xxxiii); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.