# Which of Newton's shell theorems applies to a galaxy?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, symmetry, dark-matter, galaxies, galaxy-rotation-curve

From [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/784539/) I gathered that Newton came up with two sets of shell theorems, one for hollow spheres and one for solid. It was also said we should use the version **inside a solid sphere** to model gravity within the Earth. This is indeed what the Preliminary Earth Reference Model (PREM) uses.

Of course the version **outside a sphere** (either hollow or solid) is what fits Keplerian dynamics of the solar system.

This is what yields:
$$
F = \frac{GmM(r)}{r^2} = \frac{mv^2}{r}
$$

and thus the orbital velocities of the planets:
$$
v = \sqrt{\frac{GM(r)}{r}}
$$
Isn't a galaxy more like the Earth, than the solar system (where 99% of the mass, $M(r)$, is near the center)? In that case we should model the orbital velocity of each "ring of stars" as within the sphere, rather than outside of it. Ie:
$$
M(r) = \frac{4}{3}\pi r^3\rho(r)\,,
$$
where $M(r)$ is the mass within the orbit and $\rho(r)$ is the average density enclosed by the orbit with radius $0$ to $r$ from the center.

So then plugging this in above:
$$
v = \sqrt{G\frac{4}{3}\pi r^2 \rho(r)}
$$
This makes much more sense to me, but perhaps further modification is required since a galaxy is more like an intermediate phenomenon between solar system and rocky planet. It isn't quite solid but also has a more diffuse density profile.

I've seen others also attempt to use less simplified Newtonian models, eg [this paper](https://www.mdpi.com/2075-4434/8/2/36). They conclude dark matter is not needed to explain the flat rotation curves.

Could it really be that the "missing mass" evidenced by rotation curves is due to using an oversimplified toy model? Ie, misapplying the wrong shell theorem since it is an easy calculation?

**Edit:**

Some question whether the mistake this question implies is plausible. I attempted to find otherwise but that really does seem to be how the "expected" rotation curves are arrived at. Eg, this quote is from Milgrom's first [MOND paper](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1983ApJ...270..365M/abstract):

> All determinations of dynamical mass within galaxies and galaxy systems make use of a virial relation of the form $V^2 = MGr^{-1}$ where $V$ is some typical velocity of particles in the system, $r$ is of the order of the size of the system, $M$ is the mass to be determined, and $G$ is the gravitational constant.

I would assume someone would have pointed out his mistake by now, if that wasn't the case. NB: this is *not* something that supports MOND either.

Comment: The solid sphere shell theorem is just an integration of hollow shells, not really a different theorem. At any rate, shells require uniform density, which may be a decent model of a planet but certainly not a galaxy - treating the total mass closer to the galactic center than you as a point mass at the galactic center would be a pretty poor model of the actual gravitational force you'd feel. You can calculate earth's gravity just from knowing how far from the center you are, but that's not so with a galaxy.

Comment: You think hundreds of physicists are all making a freshman-level mistake in applying Newton's law of gravity? Have you read any mainstream papers (i.e. not MDPI or other predatory journals which publish anything for money) which compute rotation curves?

Comment: The sophistication of this enterprise is a lot higher than you might be imagining. People are not staring at freshman textbooks wondering which of the equations there works. Not only do people know that stuff, there's even an industry of people who numerically compute rotation curves and galaxy structure by accounting for _all_ gravitational interactions explicitly, using supercomputers to sum the forces over billions of pairs of masses for each timestep!

Comment: @knzhou Seems unbelievable, but I have been unable to find that the "expected" velocity is calculated some other way. I'll add a quote to the edit. But if you have evidence otherwise (rather than assumptions) that is what I am asking for.

Comment: Just look at any of the foundational papers, such as [Hernquist (1990)](https://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/pdf/1990ApJ...356..359H) (with 3000 citations) or [this review (1995)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/astro-ph/9508025.pdf) (10000 citations). They actually use Newtonian mechanics to compute the rotation curves -- but they regard the calculation as so basic that they don't bother giving many details, because they expect everyone reading to easily be able to work it out themselves.

Comment: You're falling into a common trap, which is Google's fault: if you look for papers discussing a very basic point X, you're only going to find wacky ones, because the people who know what they're talking about already resolved X properly decades ago and don't bother talking about it explicitly anymore, and Google strongly favors new stuff. For future searches along these lines, try using Google Scholar and sorting by citation count, not by recency.

Comment: >`they regard the calculation as so basic that they don't bother giving many details, because they expect everyone reading to easily be able to work it out themselves`. This makes it more, not less, plausible a deeply ingrained error could persist. Anyway if you can find a paper where they do show the calculation (perhaps in some code), that would help.

Comment: Okay, backing up even more, you can try the textbook _Galactic Dynamics_ by Binney and Tremaine. Not only do they show a bunch of explicit calculations, they assign the rest as exercises, which generations of students have worked out for themselves. Seriously, we physicists do understand Newtonian mechanics. Are you a software engineer? If so, this is like claiming that everyone at Google has had all of their loops off by one for decades because they all forgot arrays start at zero.

Comment: In fact, the problem is actually the reverse of what you think it is: you've Googled up a bunch of really poor papers which _do_ make basic mistakes. But that doesn't mean mainstream physicists make such dumb mistakes. Instead, it explains why those papers are not mainstream.

Comment: "This makes it more... plausible a deeply ingrained error could persist" no, discussion thereof declined because we'd carried out exhaustive error-checking. People had every chance to make a name for themselves by exposing such errors a long time ago.

Comment: @knzhou I got a copy of the book (2015 edition). Can you tell me where you see them use the actual method to get "expected" rotation curves? I liked the idea of actually running a large N-body simulation fit to known density profiles (insofar as these are known rather than assumed). An example of that would be perfect too if you know of one.

Answer (score 2):

> Livid asked: *"Which of Newton's shell theorems applies to a galaxy?"*

For a spiral galaxy none of these theorems apply, since it is not spherical but rather approximated by a [disk with a bulge](http://notizblock.yukterez.net/viewtopic.php?t=120). Inside a disk the outer layers' gravity doesn't cancel out and the equations of motion are completely different.

> Livid asked: *"Eg, this quote is from Milgrom's first MOND paper: v²=GM/r"*

That would only work with spherical galaxies, but there aren't too many of them, if any.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149460/discussion-on-answer-by-yukterez-which-of-newtons-shell-theorems-applies-to-a-g); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.